# Get HTML element without 'For Each' loop

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I've started to do some programming in Visual Basic and I need some help. This might be a simple question but I can't figure this out.

So I have created a web browser and I would like to get the Profile Picture of a person on Facebook and display it on a Picture Box, and also the Name of that person and display it on a TextBox. After that the program should save the picture in a folder on my hard drive.

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

 Dim elemCollection As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")
    Dim fbPath As String = "C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName.ToString + "\Documents\FB Images\"


    For Each curElement As HtmlElement In elemCollection

        If curElement.OuterHtml.Contains("profilePic img") Then
            PictureBox1.ImageLocation = curElement.GetAttribute("src") 'Showing the profile pic in picture box
            TextBoxName.Text = curElement.GetAttribute("alt") 'Showing the name in a textbox
            Dim NumberOfFiles As Integer = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(fbPath).Length 
            Dim bmp As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)
            PictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, PictureBox1.ClientRectangle)
            bmp.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(fbPath, CStr(NumberOfFiles) + TextBoxName.Text + ".jpg"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

So the program should save the picture with a file name according to the number of files there is in the folder path(e.g '1 George Johnson.jpg'). But what happens, it is saving 5 different images because I guess there are more than one HTML elements that matches those attributes, so the For Each loop brings up more results.

Is there any way to get an HTML element without using this loop and just get a particular element that I want?

Comment: add more specific criteria to your `If` checking statement so that it evaluate to `True` only for the particular element that you want

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the first time the if statement for the attribute is true , add "Exit For" the line before the End If.